# Restrict combination of command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I wrote a python program which accept three optional command line arguments.However i want to restrict combination of args to be entered by user.which are :

```
python script.py -all
python script.py --country_name
python script.py --country_name --city_name
```

I any other combination program shouldn't get execute.

Note: I am using argparse python module

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier if I could see your code ... but basically, once you've run:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you can put your own validation in. eg.

```
if args.all and (args.country_name or args.city_name):
    raise MySuitableError
```

Answer (score 1):

Argparse has a [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group):

```py
import argparse

def main(parser, args):
    if args.country_city is not None:
        country, city = args.country_city
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Hello")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group.add_argument("-all")
    group.add_argument("--country_city", nargs="+")
    main(parser, parser.parse_args())
```

Which results in:

```sh
python3 test.py -all A --country_city a b
usage: test.py [-h]
                   [-all ALL | --country_city COUNTRY_CITY [COUNTRY_CITY ...]]
test.py: error: argument --country_city: not allowed with argument -all

python3 test.py --country_city a b
Namespace(all=None, country_city=['a', 'b'])

python3 test.py -all A
Namespace(all='A', country_city=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use options at all, but rather positional arguments that can be omitted.

```
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('country', nargs='?')
p.add_argument('city', nargs='?')
```

Then

```
script.py           # equiv to old script.py --all
script.py FI        # equiv to old script.py --countryname FI
script.py FI Turku  # equivalent to old script.py --countryname FI --cityname Turku
```